# Will smartphone/tablet users be able to use custom right-click context menu?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, user-experience

I am currently designing a single page web application. The UI elements of this application are dispatched in different "panels", each with specific operations.

I am considering using custom right-click context menus (in JS) for each panel. I am wondering whether  smartphone/tablet users will be able to use a web application with context menus ?

I am **not** interested in opinions about whether that is good/bad practice.

I'd rather like factual information, like: people using smartphone-OS x.x.x will have problems because there is no gesture for simulating right-click. As a matter of fact, I could not find a site summarizing this information. For instance, the awesome http://caniuse.com/#feat=menu is of no help on this.